# "Toggle" Event and "Mouseup" methods are not working here together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am simply using HTML, CSS and Javascript where I am using the "toggle" method to open and close the dropdown. Also, I am using "mouseup" method to close the dropdown when someone clicks outside of it.

But the "toggle" method is not working along with the "mouseup" method. And I also need "mouseup" method to close the dropdown when user clicks outside of it. So, please tell me the solution to it, why "toggle" is not working with "mouseup" method. Thanks in Advance.

Here is the code:

```js
var selectLabel = document.getElementById('selectLabel');

selectLabel.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let dropdownDiv = selectLabel.parentElement.querySelector('.selection-dropdown');
  selectLabel.classList.toggle('active');
  dropdownDiv.classList.toggle('show');
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  let dropdownDiv = document.querySelector('.selection-dropdown');
  if (dropdownDiv.classList.contains('show')) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('selection-dropdown') && !e.target.parentNode.closest('.selection-dropdown')) {
      selectLabel.classList.remove('active');
      document.querySelector('.selection-dropdown').classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.selection-box {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.selection-box .select-upper-label {
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #202020;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selection-box .select-upper-label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #808080;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  right: 15px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.selection-box .select-upper-label.active::after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.selection-dropdown {
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.selection-dropdown.show {
  display: block;
}

.selection-dropdown .select-all-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: royalblue;
}

.selection-dropdown .selection-dropdown-list label {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection-box">
  <label class="select-upper-label" id="selectLabel">Select options</label>

  <div class="selection-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="selectAllLink" class="select-all-link"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i> Select All</a>
    <div class="selection-dropdown-list">
      <label class="label" for="option1"><input type="checkbox" id="option1"> Option 1</label>
      <label class="label" for="option2"><input type="checkbox" id="option2"> Option 2</label>
      <label class="label" for="option3"><input type="checkbox" id="option3"> Option 3</label>
      <label class="label" for="option4"><input type="checkbox" id="option4"> Option 4</label>
      <label class="label" for="option5"><input type="checkbox" id="option5"> Option 5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why use mouseup here?

Comment: "mouseup" is to close the dropdown when anyone clicks outside of this dropdown. Thanks.

Comment: why not just another click? Have you added console logs to each event handler to confirm the functions are being called?

Comment: To identify the another click, "mouseup" event has been used here. Yes, also I have confirmed that the functions are being called on console logs.

Comment: In that case the event object ```e``` you are using in the mouseup handler is referencing the event object created by the mouseup event, so e.target would point to the document not the element of the dropdown

Comment: Yes, the "e.target" will point to the clicked element anywhere on the document. But I need to know the reason why this is preventing the "toggle" method.